# Missing space before linebreaks in PDF/UA with iText 5

Tags: itext

While creating a PDF/UA document with iText 5.5.10, every space before a linebreak seems to be removed, which appears to confuse some screenreaders. The following sample creates this text (notice no space before linebreak):

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick
brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox
jumps over the lazy dog.
```

When read in a screenreader, there are concatenated words (notice "quickbrown" and "foxjumps"):

[image: Words are concatenated in PAC]

[image: Concatenated words in NVDA Speech Viewer]

The concatenation occurs where linebreaks are put in the PDF document.

Here is a minimal sample to reproduce (*PDFAWriter and font embedding not used to make the sample smaller, since it does not appear to make a difference*):

```
package sandbox.pdfa;

import com.itextpdf.text.Chunk;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
import com.itextpdf.text.FontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class PdfUaSpike {

    static public void main(String args[]) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        final String DEST = "results/pdfa/pdfua.pdf";
        File file = new File(DEST);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        new PdfUaSpike().createPdf(DEST).showExtractedText(DEST);
    }

    public PdfUaSpike createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
        writer.setPdfVersion(PdfWriter.VERSION_1_7);
        writer.setTagged();
        writer.setViewerPreferences(PdfWriter.DisplayDocTitle);
        document.addLanguage("en-US");
        document.addTitle("English pangram");
        writer.createXmpMetadata();
        document.open();

        Font font = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 20);

        {
            Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
            p.setFont(font);

            String sampleText = IntStream.range(0, 3)
                    .mapToObj(i -> "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. ")
                    .collect(Collectors.joining());

            p.add(sampleText);
            document.add(p);
        }

        document.close();

        return this;
    }

    private void showExtractedText(String path) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Notice that spaces before linebreaks have been removed:" + System.lineSeparator());
        String extractedText = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(new PdfReader(path), 1);
        System.out.println(extractedText);
    }

}
```

Dependencies for this sample:

```
com.itextpdf:itextpdf:jar:5.5.10:compile
com.itextpdf:itext-pdfa:jar:5.5.10:compile
```

When testing a PDF exported from Word, it appears spaces before linebreaks are retained in the document, and it works fine in screenreaders.

Is there any way to configure iText to also keep the spaces before linebreaks?

The iText PDF is created in Linux and tested in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess one part of your stack creates documents with Unix [linebreaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) (LF), and another tries to "fix" windows linebreaks (CR+LF) by blindly removing the byte before LF, without checking if it's a CR in the first place.